# group using a derived field Postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have the following Postgres sql table `my_table`:

```
  type                  name
-----------------------------
 Dog_A_a_old              Spot
 Dog_B_b_b_old            Max
 Dog_C_c_c_c_old          Josh
 Dog_D_young              Woof
 Dog_E_e_young            Ball
 Cat_F_old                Snow
 Cat_G_g_g_old            Meow
 Cat_H_young              Molly
```

I would like to perform a transformation on field `type` then group using it, i.e. having a new field `d_type`:

```
  type                    name         d_type
-------------------------------------------
 Dog_A_a_old              Spot         Dog_old
 Dog_B_b_b_old            Max          Dog_old
 Dog_C_c_c_c_old          Josh         Dog_old
 Dog_D_young              Woof         Dog_young
 Dog_E_e_young            Ball         Dog_young
 Cat_F_old                Snow         Cat_old
 Cat_G_g_g_old            Meow         Cat_old
 Cat_H_young              Molly        Cat_young
```

Then I can do `select d_type, count(*) as my_count from derived_table` and get the results like:

```
d_type    my_count
------------------
Dog_old     3
Dog_young   2
Cat_old     2
Cat_young   1
```

I am wondering how to create the transformed field `d_type` and the intermediate table `derived_table` in the SQL query? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
select split_part(type, '_'::text, 1) || '_' || split_part(type, '_'::text, 3) as dtype
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff. Actually, each name has different length (I have modified the question above), would this still possible? Thank you!

Comment: @Edamame . . . The expression is a bit different.  This answers your original question.